# All bytes become zero after a zero byte

Tags: pcb, usb, raspberry-pi, serial

I'm quite new to electrical engineering, so if I didn't post something that may help to solve my problem, ask for it in comments.

I wanted to connect a Raspberry Pi 4B with a board with an STM32F779 on it.

I connected them via USB virtual COM port.

I wrote a program for the Raspberry Pi using Java and Pi4J library.

They are connected and can exchange info with each other, but when I send a byte array from the Raspberry Pi with a zero byte in it  every byte after this byte also becomes zero.

Java code:

```java
package MainPRJ;

import com.pi4j.io.serial.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class COMToCheck
{
    private static byte[] comTxData = new byte[48];

    public static void StartCOM()
    {
        Thread comThread = new Thread(() ->
        {
            // create an instance of the serial communications class
            final Serial serial = SerialFactory.createInstance();

            // create and register the serial data listener
            serial.addListener(new SerialDataEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println("[HEX DATA]   " + event.getHexByteString());
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        // logging
                    }
                }
            });

            try
            {
                // create serial config object
                SerialConfig config = new SerialConfig();
                config.device("/dev/ttyACM0")
                        .baud(Baud._57600)
                        .dataBits(DataBits._8)
                        .parity(Parity.NONE)
                        .stopBits(StopBits._1)
                        .flowControl(FlowControl.NONE);

                // open the default serial device/port with the configuration settings
                serial.open(config);

                // continuous loop to keep the program running until the user terminates the program
                while(true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // this one is OK
                        // the result on the board: 01,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,FA,FB,FC,FD,FE,FF...
//                      serial.write((byte)1, (byte)243, (byte)244, (byte)245, (byte)246, (byte)247,
//                                    (byte)248, (byte)249, (byte)250, (byte)251, (byte)252, (byte)253, (byte)254, (byte)255);

                        // this one is NOT OK
                        // the result on the board: 01,F3,F4,F5,F6,00,00,00,00,00,00,00...
                        serial.write((byte)1, (byte)243, (byte)244, (byte)245, (byte)246, (byte)0,
                                    (byte)248, (byte)249, (byte)250, (byte)251, (byte)252, (byte)253, (byte)254, (byte)255);

                    }
                    catch(IllegalStateException ex)
                    {
                        // logging
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }

            }
            catch(IOException | InterruptedException | IllegalArgumentException ex)
            {
                // logging
            }
        });
        comThread.setDaemon(false);
        comThread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        comThread.start();
    }
}
```

I receive data on my board like this:

```c
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */

   USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);

  strncpy(usbRXData,(char*)Buf,*Len);

  usbRXData[*Len]=0;

  usbIsOK = 1;

  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
```

Where could I have made a mistake?

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with null-terminated strings.

Comment: Сould you tell me anything more about this?

Comment: A zero byte is a common way of signifying the end of a string. Something might be seeing it as the end of transmission and then not attempting to send/read any more bytes.

Comment: A string in `C` is terminated with a `NULL` which is a value of `0`. So your `strncpy` call stops copying when it gets to the `0` value you sent. If you're trying to copy a block of bytes with a known size you should be using `memcpy`.

Comment: Yes, it helped! Thank you very much @Hearth and @brhans!

Comment: @brhans That should be an answer, I think!

Comment: @crackanddie:  You can write your own answer (and accept it) since you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Hearth and @brhans for their help in the comments, but for some reason @brhans doesn't leave their answer here.

As @brhans said:

> A string in C is terminated with a NULL which is a value of 0. So your strncpy call stops copying when it gets to the 0 value you sent. If you're trying to copy a block of bytes with a known size you should be using memcpy.

So I changed my code like this:

````c
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */

   USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);

  memcpy(usbRXData,(char*)Buf,*Len);

  usbRXData[*Len]=0;

  usbIsOK = 1;

  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
```
````

Comment: So did this work for you now?

Comment: yes. But it was really hard to understand that the problem was right here. I even thought that it could be because of multithreading on java and so I tried to use thread locks but it didn't help. So I spent 2 days to understand that the problem should be in board firmware.

Comment: Okay, then you can mark this answer as solution.

Comment: yes, but I can mark it only after a day after answering :) so do not worry about it